# Email-to-Case Premium with custom object

Tags: custom-object, appexchange, email2case, case-comment

I'm having a custom object called "Case_Comments__c" which performs the same functionality as standard case comments does. I'm planning to install Email-to-Case Premium this month. I know E2CP will add the email body as case comments( one of the features in it) whenever the email is sent or received.

My question here is will E2CP be compatible with the custom object I use here? What will be the limitations if I use E2CP with custom object.

Anyone worked on E2CP before, please help me out.

Comment: Why dont you data migrate your custom case comments to the standard one? Why would you need a custom one when there is a standard one for the same

Comment: The reason is, I'm using an inline VF page in case details page in which I want to display the case comments as Rich Text field and also I want more than 4k characters to be entered in the comment body. For these couple of reasons, I am using custom case comment object

Comment: Have you asked E2CP support?

Comment: Yes @David but they haven't got back to me on this yet. That's why I posted the question here so that somebody who worked on this already would provide me an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the reply from E2CP support that they won't support any custom object for this scenario. Also they have provided me some inputs that my demands as mentioned in my comment to David can be achieved in their app config itself.

1. To display case comments in Rich Text format.
2. To increase comment body limit.

Thanks everyone for your valuable time.